# How To Count Number Of Words From Preg Match Result

Tags: php

I have a code that removes comma from list of words and separate all words. I tried counting the number of words in the string (which also contain mail addresses and words) from the result, but it returns 00000 instead of just 5. How do I resolve this issue. below is my code

```
$input = "example@k.c, bar@h.c, baz@h.c., shibbyc, poopc.";

//-- handles it all in one pass
$output = preg_split('/(,)/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);


//-- just output
array_walk($output, function(&$item, $idx) {

echo substr_count($item,$idx);

 //  echo $idx . ': ' . $item . PHP_EOL;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use [`count()`](http://php.net/count) :

```
$output = preg_split('/(,)/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo count($output); // 5
```

Comment: @user74651 This anwser has one downvote and one upvote, so -1+1=0 :)

Comment: @user74651 Another note about your regular expression, your brackets are not required: `'/,/'` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex, just use explode.
Much less memory hungry function.
And count off course.

```
$input = "example@k.c, bar@h.c, baz@h.c., shibbyc, poopc.";
$arr = explode(",", $input);

Echo count($arr); //echo 5
```

https://3v4l.org/SLBnc